# Using "V" to represent vowels in user input in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I need to run a query, in which the user inputs a string, and then the query returns any records, in which any part of the data matches a string. For example, the parameter "w" would return "wa", "ew", etc. I can do this easily enough:

```
SELECT 
    getSourceID.Title, getSourceID.Author, 
    word.form, word.gloss, word.pageNumber, 
    getSourceID.Publication
FROM 
    getSourceID 
INNER JOIN 
    word ON getSourceID.[ID] = word.[source]
WHERE 
    (((word.form) LIKE "*" & Forms!FsearchByForm!contains & "*") 
    AND ((getSourceID.Publication) Between Forms!FsearchByForm!minYear And Forms!FsearchByForm!maxYear));
```

But alas my SQL isn't very good. I need to extend this so that V and C can represent a vowel or consonant respectively, i.e. a parameter "Vw" would return any instances in which the record contained "aw", "ow", etc.

Is there a way of implementing this into a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a character range in a `Like` pattern ...

```sql
SELECT
    "abc" Like "*[aeiouy]*" AS test_true,
    "bcd" Like "*[aeiouy]*" AS test_false
```

The same technique would work in a `WHERE` clause.  But I'm unsure how you would apply that when the pattern comes from a text box (`Forms!FsearchByForm!contains`).

Perhaps you could do a `Replace()` on the text box value, and figure out a method to distinguish when a *V* is intended to be a vowel placeholder and when it's supposed to be just the letter *V*.

Comment: One might debate if "y" is a vowel, but this is correct.

Comment: This is perfect! _C_ and _V_ will not be input for this particular set, so that's fine. One issue I have though, is I don't know how to get both Replace() clauses to happen simultaneously?
So when I do `Replace(Forms!FsearchByEnvrionment!environment, "V", "*[aioue]*")`, it works as I expect, same for `Replace(Forms!FsearchByEnvrionment!environment, "C", "*[bmthnldrjkgw]*")` (which is all the consonants I need). But how do I do these in unison? Combining the two using _&_ simply returns nothing. AsI still need input such as _CVC_ to return results!
Thank you so much!

Comment: You could "nest" the `Replace()` expressions --- use the output from the first as the input for the second.  Something like this: `Replace(Replace(Forms!FsearchByEnvrionment!environment, "V", "*[aioue]*"), "C", "*[bmthnldrjkgw]*")`

Comment: But that would make a fairly challenging query.  I would consider adding a hidden text box, *like_pattern*, to the form.  Then load *like_pattern* with the nested `Replace()` from the After Update event of *environment*, and use *like_pattern* in the query.  Essentially, do the `Replace()` work in the form instead of in the query.